# Multiple dynamic table dynamically and simultaneously with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to load 2 table dynamically (in `#txtHint` and `#txtHint2`) with data from MySQL tables.

I am using 2 functions for this. but only one table is loading at the time. I think I need to concatenate the 2 functions but I don't know how.

Here are my form and the script file. I have checked both function works well by switching its position in this:

```
onchange="showDevices2(this.value), showUser(this.value) "
```

**form**

```
<body>
    <div>           
        <input id="name" type="text" name="part_id" onchange="showDevices2(this.value), showUser(this.value) " />      
    </div>
    <div id="tables">    
        <div id="table1">
            <div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
        </div>          
        <div id="table2">
            <div id="txtHint2"><b></b></div>
        </div>  
    </div>                  
</body>
```

**global.js**

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML =  xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../action/subs/getcalls.php/?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}


function showDevices2(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../action/subs/getdevices_list.php/?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

**getdevices_list.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                table {
                    width: 100%;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                }

                table, td, th {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    padding: 5px;
                }

                th {text-align: left;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

            <?php


                $q = intval($_GET['q']);

                include '../db/connect.php';

                mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
                $sql="SELECT * FROM oz2ts_devices WHERE member_id = '".$q."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                echo "<table class=\"optable\">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Device ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Make & Model</th>
                        <th>Memory</th>
                    </tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['device_id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['device_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['device_type'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['make_model'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['memory'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**getcalls.php**

Same as `getdevices_list.php` but getting data from different database table.

Both table have same user ID.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onchange` handler.

You have this:

```
onchange="showDevices2(this.value), showUser(this.value)"
```

But instead of the comma (`,`), you should have a semi-colon (`;`):

```
onchange="showDevices2(this.value); showUser(this.value)"
```

This should allow you to "concatenate" the two functions (run them back-to-back).

Comment: Thank you for your help but only the second in the list still loadiing at the time.

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate the functions to have only function filling the 2 tables?

Comment: @JulyJames Yes. You can simply put the content of both functions into one single function.

Comment: can you help on how to put both content in a single function? I have tried but haven't been able to get it work.